# Could someone have gathered files from my local system via a GitHub repo? I see that DS_Store files might open up this possibility

Tags: javascript, github, filesystems, local, public-folders

Today I went into a GitHub repository I haven't worked on in a month or so since completing a bootcamp. It is a personal project where I have basically just seeded some database tables and had uploaded an image or two and started a React app displaying those.
When I went on today, in the public images folder was a **profile photo** and also a photo of my **passport visa**. I don't recall adding those! and can't see that it would've even been an accident, though maybe I suppose.
Could having my fairly rookie code available to see on GitHub have led to me leaving something open for someone to get those files from my local system? I'm not sure how that would work but did read a little about .DS_Store files on Mac and there was one of those uncommitted in there too.
Can anyone shed any insight? Is it possible/likely someone scanned my files and grabbed those images for whatever reason?
I deleted the photos and ds_store file.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is why I always do a `git status`, before a `git commit`: to double-check what I am about to commit.

Unless someone has direct access to your machine, nobody else should have been able to add a personnel file but you.

And remember: deleting the file only removes it from the most recent commit, not from past commits.
Only a tool like [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (python-based) would allow you to remove it from all past commits, which changes the history and require a `git push --force` (not a big deal if you are the only one working on the repository).